# How to integrate Angular 2 to existing J2EE Spring project and Run it on same PORT?

Tags: spring, angular, npm

I have existing project with a Spring on a back-end and **AngularJS 1** on front-end. When I run the Spring server - opens just 1 port for me: 8080 and I can access REST APIs and also **AngularJS** front-end stuff through it.

[image]

But now I want to move to new **Angular 2**.
How do I make it use same port: 8080 both for APIs and **Angular 2**? 
The reason why I asking about this, is that almost each tutorial that I find offers to use Angular CLI(npm install -g angular-cli) https://cli.angular.io/ stuff that installs another lite server with it and then I have to run it on a different port.

How to install minimum required dependencies for **Angular 2** and without its own Server?

Like tutorial like that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhroyiYFmjc
REST API run on port: 8080
Angular2 on port: 3000

Comment: Did you try to modify the output file location in the config file? The key is to output a "main.js" file in the specified location and include the main.js in your HTML.

Answer (score 3):

To deploy your app generated by Angular CLI under your Java server, you can run ng build (or ng build --prod) and copy the content of the files generated in the dist dir to your server to the static dir.

In dev mode, if you want to keep running the app with the dev server (it runs on the port 4200 by default), you can configure a proxy by creating a file proxy-config.json in your Angular project with the following content (assuming the api is the part of the deployed URL):

`{   "/api": { 

      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
     "secure": false   }
 }`

Now you can run the app in dev mode using the following command:

`ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

This will allow your dev server (port 4200) to access the REST API on port 8080.

Comment: Is it right that build folder does not contain *.ts files? Because I write all my code in TypeScript..

Comment: I tried it, and it did not work. It created for me few files in /dist folder: favicon.ico,  index.html, inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.map, main.bundle.js, main.bundle.map, styles.bundle.css, ... etc. And when I run Java Spring project and try to load index.html I get bunch of errors in Chrome: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <